# Withdrawal symptoms of pornography addiction

Tags: brain, addiction, dopamine

For a 10 years pornography addict what are the symptoms of withdrawal at the first 2 months ?

Comment: This might be better served in CogSci as it is further to the psychology end of the health spectrum?

Comment: I could see how the OP's asking about withdrawal symptoms relative to health. Even if it's mental health, still seems relevant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, porn addiction withdrawal is also equivalent to dopamine withdrawal.  The chemicals that your brain creates when you use porn – Dopamine and Delta Fos-B – are the exact same ones it creates when you use cocaine or meth.

[Dopamine](https://www.psychologytoday.com/basics/dopamine) is a neurotransmitter that helps control the brain's reward and pleasure centers. Dopamine also helps regulate movement and emotional responses, and it enables us not only to see rewards, but to take action to move toward them.

During the first to seventh (1-7) day of porn withdrawal, your brain's still in shock. During this period, such symptoms persist:

1. Grumpiness - Every little thing will irritate you
2. Mood swings - This is mainly due to the fact that the brain is still trying to rebalance itself.
3. Headaches
4. Anxiety - Some men have legitimate panic attacks.
5. Pornographic thoughts - Obviously, during the first few weeks of porn withdrawal, you keep having lustful thoughts, causing you to remember your last pornographic experience.

Between the fourth to eighth (4th-8th) week, majority of men begin to feel the withdrawal symptoms wear out, if you aren't, there's no problem, just keep enduring. During this period, the following symptoms persist:

1. Random Temptation - You might have made it so far, only to have a bad day that sends you back into relapse.
2. Insomnia - This occurs mainly to those who are heavily addicted to porn. It's almost impossible to treat, as over-the-counter sleep aids might be of much help.
3. Depression - Not all mean suffer depression, as this mainly occurs during the early stages of porn withdrawal. It's uncommon for it last several weeks, but it always eventually goes.

For more info, visit [this](http://husbandhelphaven.com/porn-addiction-withdrawal-walkthrough/) site and [this](http://husbandhelphaven.com/porn-addiction-symptoms/) for info on how porn morphs the brain. I hope I was able to answer your question correctly.

Comment: You might have a good answer here but you make a lot of assertions of fact with no supporting sources. For example, you state that porn withdrawal is equivalent to dopamine withdrawal. Oh, says who? And your list of symptoms of porn withdrawal -- where did that come from? For all we know you just made it up. Please add citations supporting your  factual claims or you risk having your answer downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: I agree, this seems feasible but resources are needed

Comment: There's a group called The New Drug that has more on the science of porn